# wicked wizard passing arguments to steps

Tags: process, wizard

I would like to make a smooth streamlined process for placing customer orders. 
I feel the best tool for the job is a wizard - unless there are other suggestions?

I need to pass arguments to next steps in my wizard.

My controller looks like this:

```
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :item, :customization, :upsell

def show
# @order_session_id = params[:order_session_id]

@order = Order.new
@order.order_session_id = params[:order_session_id]

case step
when :item
    @items = Item.all # change with group...
when :customization
    # item = Item.find(@order.item_id)
    # item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    item = Item.find(1)
    @customizations = item.customizations.split("|")
when :upsell
    @upsells = Upsell.find_all_by_group_id(item.group_id)
end

render_wizard
end

def update
    @order_session_id = params[:order_session_id]
    @order.attributes = params[:order]
    render_wizard @order
end
```

The view for item looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @order, url: wizard_path(:customization), :method => :get do |f| %>

  <table border="1">
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>        
        <td class="item_selection" onclick="$(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked');return false;">
            <%= f.label :item_id, "#{item.name}" %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:item_id, item.id) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Continute" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I need to pass the selected item_id to the customization step so that the next part of the wizard can work.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in the url after the step parameter.

```
wizard_path(:step_1, item: item)
```